# Why do we need to use position: relative for css image gallery?

Tags: html, css

In the following code for image gallery:

http://alpatriott.ru/works/album/

The following styles were used:

```
.gallery{
     margin:0 auto;
     width:800px;
     height:640px;
     background:#333;
     box-shadow:0px 0px 15px 1px #333;
     -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 15px 1px #333;
     -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 15px 1px #333;
     position:relative;
}
a{
float:left;
width:25%;
height:25%;
position:relative;
border:1px solid #333;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
a img{
       display:block;
       width:100%;
       height:100%;
       -webkit-transition-property:width, height;
       -webkit-transition-duration:300ms;
       -moz-transition-property:width, height;
       -moz-transition-duration:300ms;
       -o-transition-property:width, height;
       -o-transition-duration:300ms;
       position:absolute;
       z-index:1;
       opacity:0.3;
       cursor:pointer;
 }

<div class="gallery">
    <a tabindex="1"><img src="images/smile.jpg"></a>
    <a tabindex="1"><img src="images/smile.jpg"></a>
    </div>
```

I am not able to figure out why they used relative here.

There are other image galleries which don't seem to use position: relative for instance in the following code:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_gallery.asp

```
<div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="klematis_big.htm">
        <img src="klematis_small.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>

div.img
{
     margin:2px;
     border:1px solid #0000ff;
     height:auto;
     width:auto;
     float:left;
     text-align:center;
}
div.img img
{
     display:inline;
     margin:3px;
     border:1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

According to the definition:

The element is positioned relative to its normal position, so "left:20" adds 20 pixels to the element's LEFT position. (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

For my code above (first instance), there was no relative distance like left:20px mentioned. I would like to know why and when to use relative. and why we needed in this example one above.

Thanks

Comment: Here is a nice article about css positioning: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They have used `position: relative;` there because they have a nested `absolutely` positioned element, so when you have an element `positioned absolute` you need to wrap the element with a `position: relative;` container, else it will flow out in the wild..

I will share 2 demos with you, one with positioned relative container and other without the position relative container

[**Demo 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fp6cA/) (Position Relative container)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fp6cA/1/) (Without Position Relative container)

Note: Elements which use `position: relative;` doesn't mean that it will always hold `absolute` positioned elements, it may not contain absolute elements, because if the designer wants to use `top` and `left` properties, he need to use `position: relative;` there as `top` and `left` won't work on `static` position.

[**Demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fp6cA/2/) (Relative Position)

[**Demo 4**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fp6cA/3/) (Static Position)

> Also, this logic doesn't apply ONLY to CSS Gallery, it's a positioning
>   concept in CSS. You can read some detailed tutorials on CSS
>   Positioning

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice explanation. I am not sure how the child element is absolute - only the declaration is absolute but there are no co-ordinates specified. Then how is it acting as absolutely positioned?

Comment: @user285825 It depends, what if there's a binded JS with the element, which will use inline styles of top and left? Also, if you don't specify the top left right bottom properties, the absolute div will just render where it is placed, for example.. if the designer needs too zoom images, or say add borders than he needs to use position absolute for the images else it will disturb the layout...

Answer (score 0):

A child element is always positioned absolute or relative to his parent. so it is important to make child and parent elements, except you want a div as a placeholder to load the data in another way...

may play arround with the code (why is position:absolute 5px top and left only 5px from the orange...) it may helps to understand

http://jsfiddle.net/ZKP6q/

```
<div class="app-header">xxx
    <div class="main-app-area"> <!-- app contains four pages -->
        yyy
        <div class="app-page active">zzz</div>
        <div class="app-page"></div>
        <div class="app-page"></div>
        <div class="app-page"></div>
        <div class="app-page"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.app-header
{
    background-color:green;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 100%;

}
.main-app-area
{
    background-color:orange;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
}

.app-page
{
    background-color:fuchsia;
    opacity:0.5;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    visibility: hidden;

}
.app-page.active {
    visibility:visible;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

"Position: relative" in a container element not only makes other positions within the element relative to the container; it also starts a new stacking context for `z-index`. The new stacking context means that the `img` elements will appear above anything that came before them, even if they had a higher `z-index`. You can find this explained with graphics in http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Answer (score 0):

Well there may be plenty of reasons for that, but personally I loved it when I had to overlap something.

Its mostly used-in the element when I know the inner element of that element is going to be positioned absolutely.

For example If I have two divs and outside div is a static block and elements inside the outer div is going to be positioned absolute relative to the outer div. Then use position:relative for the outer div and inner div should use position:absolute. Now the inner div elements can be placed anywhere using top, bottom, left and right attributes of CSS.
Read More about positioning elements here http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp

Also look at http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/

(there're lots of examples) CSS positioning can be especially useful when you need to position something that cannot be positioned within normal flow.